# Download file with AFNetworking in swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking, nsprogress

I want to download file from URL using AFNetworking in swift, and show downloading progress. I have this code, but it doesn't work:

```
func downloadPdf()
{
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.sa.is/media/1039/example.pdf"))
    let session = AFHTTPSessionManager()

    var progress: NSProgress?

    var downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: &progress, destination: {(file, responce) in self.pathUrl},
        completionHandler:
        {
            response, localfile, error in
            println("response \(response)")
        })

    downloadTask.resume()
}

var pathUrl: NSURL
{
    var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var url = NSURL(string: path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("file.pdf"))
    println(url.path)
    return url
}
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? Did you print NSLog to see what are you getting?

Comment: By the way, take a look at **[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)** - that's some kickass swiftish stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `pathUrl` computed property. If you print the URL (rather than `url.path`), you'll see that your URL is not valid. That's because you're using `NSURL(string:)`, and for file URLs, you should use `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)`. Thus:

```
var pathUrl: NSURL {
    let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!
    let documentsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsFolder)
    return documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.pdf")
}
```

Or, even better, bypass the path altogether, and use `URLForDirectory` to get the `.DocumentDirectory` as a URL:

```
var pathUrl: NSURL {
    return try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
}
```

Or in Swift 3:

```
var pathUrl: URL {
    return try! FileManager.default.urlForDirectory(.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
}
```